# boxcar averaging algorithm of the specified weight

Tags: java, algorithm, math

Ok, I need to write a java algorithm which simulates the [SMOOTH function](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/SMOOTH.html) written in [IDL](http://www.exelisvis.com/ProductsServices/IDL/Language.aspx). But I'm not quite sure how that algorithm works. The smooth equation is given by:
[image]

I know there is already a similar [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37059/what-is-boxcar-averaging) regarding boxcar averaging. But the algorithm seems to be different.

What I understand in this equation is that there is two states (if statement), the first one is calculating the weight average, the second one is to ignore the boundary.

In the first equation, I think I got the summation notation, it starts from 0 to (w - 1).

What I don't get is the one inside summation `Ai+j-w/2`.

The following is the sample data (just corner part of large data) that was calculated using IDL. I used weight 5 to calculate this.

[image]

Please, explain me how that algorithm works.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `i`'th average to be from a window around the `i`'th point.  So it has to start before that point, and end after.

Subtracting off `w/2` in the index causes `j=0` to be the start of the window you want, and `j=w-1` to be the end of the window you want.

It would be entirely equivalent to sum from `j=-w/2` to `j=w/2-1` instead.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it is that simple. When I looked at the equation, I was so confused.